# How would life on a planet without seasons evolve?

Tags: evolution, life, seasons

This also counts intelligent life as well, but I've been working on my universe more and have been considering planets without an axial tilt (thus not allowing seasons).

What kind of plants and animals would exist on the planet, if there would be any?

Comment: What makes you think that a lack of seasons would have any major impact on existence of life?

Comment: There is so little detail defined for this world of your own creation that there can be no good answer to this. I strongly suggest you take some time to better define your world. Even then, this would be dependent only on opinions, because evolution isn't a deterministic system.

Comment: @Frostfyre Evolution as such isn't determinstic, as you say, but we can still reason about whether a factor is likely to present meaningful selective pressure or not. So this might not necessarily be purely opinion-based (as Cort Ammon pointed out, we do have nearby examples to work from), but I do still think that it needs more details on why OP thinks lack of seasons would be a problem for life in the first place.

Comment: For future questions I ask, I'll be sure to add more detail. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things:

1. Seasons could be produced in other ways than axial tilt; an eccentric orbit (which is oval rather than circular) could produce seasons in a world without an axial tilt because the planet is at a different distance from the star at various times during its orbital path.
2. 'Animals' and 'Plants' may not be useful concepts when considering alien biology. Think instead of autotrophs (that can transform energy, like heat, electromagnetic, magnetic or nuclear energy from the environment into chemical energy needed to power their internal processes) and heterotrophs (that can only get chemical energy by consuming autotrophs). These definitions are based on ecology/quasi-thermodynamics and are much more likely to be universal throughout the universe.
3. A biosphere on a planet with no axial tilt would still experience temperature changes based on day/night cycles unless it was tide-locked (one side always facing the star). The degree of change would depend on atmospheric composition and density. A highly dense atmosphere would retain and distribute heat much more efficiently than a planet with a low atmospheric density. Greenhouse gas composition would also help maintain heat at night. Co2, water vapour, methane and halogenated gases are all greenhouse gases; some of the CFCs used in fridges are thousands of times better at heating the atmosphere up than CO2 for example.
4. Biomes on earth that don't experience seasons (typically equatorial) exhibit the greatest number of species, the highest degree of interspecies interconnections and the greatest level of competition. These biomes are typically hugely complex. Organisms tend to become highly specialised and to focus on one type of food as many plants produce poisons to ensure that only specialists (immune to their poison) can eat them. This happens because, with seasons, different organisms become specialists at different points in the season. Without seasons, all the organisms are forced to compete all of the time. This encourages things like poison, the ability to move in normally sessile organisms like plants, unusual ways of feeding (plants that can eat animals), lures, and organisms using other organisms as their niche (parasites, epiphytes, commensuals and symbiotes).

Comment: In our solar system, orbits are generally ellipses (ovals) rather than circles.  An eccentric orbit is merely more elliptical.

Answer (score 5):

Seasons aren't really mandatory for life.  Consider, for instance, the jungles of the equator, where there is not much distinction from one season to the next.  The growing season is pretty much all year long.

You would see more specialization, with one fewer cycles to worry about.  As you approach the poles, the transition from where deciduous trees have an advantage to where evergreens have an advantage would likely be sharper because there wouldn't be a huge rush of a growing season in the spring.

Animals are equally flexible.  However, you wouldn't see any major migratory birds, or hibernating animals.  The advantages of those sorts of lives just won't be important without the seasons.